# How to auto-enable Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation

I have a Chrome extension used in corporate environment. It is installed automatically by our installer from Chrome extensions store. However the user have to enable it manually after installation, which is very annoying.

We have all extension sources, so we can modify it as required, sign, publish, etc.

Are there any way to enable Chrome extension automatically?

Comment: Any explanation of what is wrong with the question instead of blantly downvote it?

Comment: I see similar questions asked e.g. [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/1G-C1EOZwks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a corporate environment, you can force any extension to be installed using [`ExtensionInstallForcelist` policy setting](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist).

Not only it will be automatically installed, it will also be impossible for the user to disable it.